# Android what's Difference between save image to Gallery and SDCARD,And How to save both?

Tags: android

Android how to save image in Gallery? and what's difference between save image to gallery or in sdcard Please Explain ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not really save an image file into the gallery.The gallery is a native android app designed to show the image and video files on the SD card. However,when you save some media files into SD card, you can notify the mediascanservice to update the database of the gallery so that these files will be shown in gallery (by default ,not shown ).
see here:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html